# XSL: how to put substring to xsl:attribute - part of url adress

Tags: xml, sharepoint, xslt

I code custom search result page on Sharepoint.
I've got a problem with XSLT.

Search result from SP is something like:

```
<Result>
...
<url>http://server/_bdc/name/source.aspx?id=444</url>
...
</Result>
```

But I want to make own link, from this url variable I want to cut only the id (444):

```
<a href="http://mynewlink/page.aspx?id=444">MyResult</a>
```

I tried something like (based on standard SP template)

```
...
<a>
<xsl:attribute name="href">        
{concat('http://mynewlink/page.aspx?id=', substring-after("{url}", "="))}
</xsl:attribute>
</a>
...
```

but it didn't work - I don't know where put this concat...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your code is "almost" correct, start by replacing**:

```
"{url}"
```

**with**:

```
url
```

**Here is a complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <a href=
       "http://mynewlink/page.aspx?id={substring-after(url,'=')}">MyResult</a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Result>
 ...
 <url>http://server/_bdc/name/source.aspx?id=444</url>
 ...
</Result>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<a href="http://mynewlink/page.aspx?id=444">MyResult</a>
```